# Behaviour of event.stopPropagation(); in different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `event.stopPropagation();` method of `jquery` to stop bubbling of events.

But i am not sure if it works for all browsers as it is. Can any one please help in making it work for all browsers

> eg :Ie(7,8,9,10),firefox,chrome.

Comment: Ya, it is normalized in jQuery.

Comment: thank you Wolf. I tested it and i think its working.

Comment: Well, if it is a jQuery method than that should mean it works in all officially supported browsers unless the docs say otherwise.

Comment: "*please help in making it work*" sounds as if you had experienced problems with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation();` is a intelligent function, once you have included JQuery library which uses pure JavaScript , handles every browser.

Answer (score 0):

`event.stopPropagation()` is normalized across browsers, so it should work on all platforms and all browsers. As a general practice `event.stopPropagation` is used in combination with `event.preventDefault` and these two actions are equal with `return false` statement.

```
function() {
  return false;
}

// IS EQUAL TO

function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is really helpful